# English command [text RPG] - python

Tags: python

I am creating a text-RPG taking inspiration from older text adventures where the player enters an English command; such as 'pick up sword' and the like.
I have established a simple; enter 'A' to do this and enter 'B' to do this, but I would like to expand my system for more freedom.
I need to create a system that; when the player types in a command the program picks out key words.
I assume this would be achievable via the 'in' command.
Here is my code:

```
print "What would you like to do??"
input_loop_sleep = str('')
choice_sleep = raw_input(str('>>>'))
loop_sleep = False
table_time = False
bed_time = False
error_time = False



while loop_sleep == False:


    if str('sleep') in choice_sleep or str('bed') in choice_sleep or str('goodnight') in choice_sleep or str('Sleep') in choice_sleep or str('tired') in choice_sleep:
        while bed_time == False:
            print "you decide to go back to sleep"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print ""
            time.sleep(1)
            print "darkness"
            time.sleep(1)
            print ""
            print "you wake up..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "it is now 9:15am"
            time == int(9.15)
            time.sleep(1)
            print "You are standing in your room, slightly more refreshed."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "there is a table with some things on it, stairs, and a wardrobe... with the doors wide open..."
            time.sleep(1)
            print "that's strange... you swear that they were shut when you went to sleep..."
            break
        else:
            bed_time == True
        break
        bed_loop_choice = raw_input('>>>')



    elif str('bedside') in choice_sleep or str('table') in str(choice_sleep):
        while table_time == False: 
            print "You rub your eyes and pick up some belongings from a"
            print "bedside table."
            time.sleep(1) 
            print "Map added!"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "100 gold added!"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Leather Bag added!"
            cash == int(100)
            time.sleep(1)
            Map == str('map of', str(province))
            Inventory == [str(Map)]
            container == str('leather bag')
            print "your", str(container), str("contains a"), str(Map), str('and'), str(cash)
            break
        else:
            table_time == True
        break

    else:
        print "invalid command!"
```

when I run the code, no matter what I type in it always goes with the 'sleep' option.
I probably just made some simple mistake!
can you please help me with what I did wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: The download is not public.  Please try to make your question self-contained.

Comment: Please describe your problem in better detail, and post your relevant code here.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question about why the `sleep` loop is repeated all the time:

You're controlling the loop via

```
while bed_time == False:
```

but you never set `bed_time` to `True` in your loop (only in the `else` clause, but that clause is only executed when the loop exits normally, *not* when it's exited via `break`, as you're now doing - therefore `bed_time` will never change).

Furthermore, direct comparisons to a boolean value are usually frowned upon. The idiomatic way (in most languages, not just Python) would be `while not bedtime:`.

You should probably read some beginners' programming books and/or the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) before embarking on such a big project. There are several issues in your code that convey the impression that you really need to get a grasp on some basic programming principles and Python idioms.

For example,

```
int(9.15)
```

is not a good way to store a time - the result will be `9`.

You're then using `time == int(9.15)`, which means "compare the module `time` to  the integer `9`". I guess you meant `time = int(9.15)` which is already bad for the reasons stated above, but there would be even another problem: You would be overwriting the module name `time`, which will cause the subsequent `time.sleep(1)` command to fail with an `AttributeError`.

There's no need for most `str()` calls in your code because you're using it on objects that already *are* strings. Where you're not, it's incorrect: `str('map of', str(province))` will raise `TypeError` (`str` takes only one argument).

You're using uppercase variable names for objects that aren't class instances.

Etc., etc...

Comment: I'd also note that == is not an assignment operator in Python, only a comparison operator.

Comment: @llb: Wow, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be sufficient to sort out the problem

```
 In [1]: str('bed') in "bedside"
 Out[1]: True
```

So when you write `bedside` it gets inside the `sleep` option if condition and hence you are getting wrong answer .

You should write :

```
 if str('bed') == choice_sleep or *other conditions* :
    then got inside the sleep option
```

P.S: I am assuming you have imported the `time` module .
P.P.S: I checked the code with entering `table` it is working fine .